# How do I check the transmission fluid levels in an 2008 Opel Combo C?

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, opel, transmission-fluid

How can I check the level of tbe transmission fluid in my 2008 Opel Combo C manual?

I recently experience problems with my transmission/changing gears and would like to check my transmission fluid levels. This seems to be harder than expected since there is no easy pull-out thing like the one for the motor oil.
Is there an easy way to to this or any ideas where to look? The manual was not helpful.

Thanks! And Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! No worries about your English ... you're doing just fine :o) As for your answer, I don't know about your Opel, but there's a lot of cars out there which require you to check it by how much runs out of a plug in the bottom, with the car completely level and up to temp. It's a REALLY terrible way to do it for the guy at home who wants to check it for themselves. Again, not sure on your Opel, but yah ... great fun.

Comment: Thanks! I read that too, can't find the plug though and it's a very hard thing to do on the roadside :/ Really bad design :D